# Zend Query Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

Hi i need to do a simple query but something is wrong. I have $name and $surname and i need to search the (possible multiple) id that rappresent that name and surname and put all the id, name and surname in a array
I do this query:

```
$result=$this->_db_table->select()->where('name=?',$name)
    ->where('surname=?', $surname)->query()
    ->fetchAll();

$array=$result->toArray();
return $array;
```

If i use

```
$result=$this->_db_table->fetchAll();
$array=$result->toArray();
return $array
```

it work correctly and i have an array whith all the value in the database in that table. What is wrong in my first code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing this

```
$result=$this->_db_table->select()->where('name=?',$name)
    ->where('surname=?', $surname)->query()
    ->fetchAll();
```

$result is already an array its not an object . So simply use it instead of calling toArray on it.

Correct  code wd be

```
$result=$this->_db_table->select()->where('name=?',$name)
    ->where('surname=?', $surname)->query()
    ->fetchAll();

return $result;
```